# split string without brackets and ensure quotes around each word

Tags: ruby

I have strings in the following format `one-word-after-another` as an example. What I need is these to be outputted in the following format `'one', 'word', 'after', 'another'`

I have tried `'one-world-after-another'.split("-")` but the output adds brackets which I dont need.

```
'one-world-after-another'.split("-")
=> ["one", "world", "after", "another"]
```

I know this is because its an Array.

Can anyone recommend a way to achieve the outcome `'one', 'word', 'after', 'another'`

Comment: What do you mean by "output"? Print to console or what?

Comment: what is your goal?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Better than my answer. Post it as one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
puts 'one-world-after-another'.split("-").map {|e| "'#{e}'"}.join(", ")
```

This produces:

```
'one', 'world', 'after', 'another'
```

Comment: `map(&:inspect)` might also do the job if the type of quotes don't matter.

Comment: @tadman: True. I generally try to avoid using `inspect` for formatting because it's intended to be a debugging function whose output style could (theoretically) change at any time between Ruby versions. Granted, they probably won't change the output formatting of strings, but still. Additionally, if the strings contained newlines, binary data, or something else that inspect would print as an escape code, the result would very much not be the same.

Comment: Good point there with the format being somewhat arbitrary even if it has remained fairly consistent for strings. I hope this code isn't expected to deal with things like `hasn't-isn't-O'Reilly`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to split the string, manipulate the resulting array and convert it back into a string. Just modify the string and add a double-quote on each end.

```
str = 'one-world-after-another'

puts "\"#{str.gsub('-', '", "')}\""
```

prints

```
"one", "world", "after", "another"
```

Comment: No around each of the words

Answer (score 0):

If you need a string with the format you are looking for, then do this

```
"one-word-after-another".split('-').map{|word| "'#{word}'"}.join(', ')
=> "'one', 'word', 'after', 'another'"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"one-word-after-another".split('-').map {|word| "'" + word + "'" }.join(', ')
```

Considering that the guy who asked the question has split the string already and is looking for a way to complete his code. I just thought i could build up on what he is already aware of.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)